# How to assign addEventListener as ON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

How to assign `addEventListener` as on
in pure JavaScript? Not jQuery.

```js
// i can do this
// assigning document as d
// assigning querySelector as $

const d = document
const $ = x => d.querySelector(x)

//but how to do this

$('button').addEventListener('click',doSomething)

//to

$('button').on('click',doSomething)

//assiging addEventListener as on
```

Comment: The *easy* way would be to have a function `on` which takes the element, event and handler as arguments: `on($('button'), 'click', doSomething)`. While extending DOM elements is possible, I think it may still be frowned upon? Not sure. And introducing wrapper objects around DOM elements would certainly be less "easy".

Comment: @FelixKling i tried this. but could not control actions while working with several elements.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means...

Comment: I mean 

if i use 2 buttons then what happens.

when the on function is going to run on which event
how do i specify that

and this on funtion has same 3 arguments

Comment: If you have two buttons are you going to call `on` twice: `on($('button1'), 'click', doSomething); on($('button2'), 'click', doSomething)`.

Comment: yes thanks...maybe i was doing something wrong while trying this method earlier

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own `on()` function -

```
function on(object, event, callback) {
    object.addEventListener(event, callback);
}
```

Or you could look into prototyping for object functions - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by saying simple, but here is the alternative way:

```
document.getElementById("id").onclick = doSomething;
```

Comment: What about this do you consider "better" that you'd recommend it over `addEventListener`?

Comment: Well, it is kind of subjective, it depends on your need. The top answer here explains it very well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Comment: Oh, I know what the differences are, I was just wondering whether you have a specific reason for suggesting this over any other solution that involves `addEventListener`, considering the limitations this solution has.

Comment: yes, you definitely do I believe, no particular reason other than the OP had already used  `addEventListener` along with jQuery, so I tried  to show alternative way, assuming it would be simpler for the OP to use `onclick`

Comment: I see. FWIW, the OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: my bad, I just got accustomed to jQuery way of $ I haven't seen function declaration in the beginning, thanks for pointing it out